# How do I make apt-get update download packages for earlier versions of Ubuntu?

Tags: apt, updates, 15.10

I have Ubuntu Wily Werewolf (15.10), and for pretty much all of the packages I get from ppa, there's not a `wily` subdirectory, so instead of installing it gives me a 404 error. Can I force `apt-get update` to download sources for previous versions of Ubuntu (I assume they'll still work)?

I apologise if this question is dumb; I'm fairly new to Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you added a PPA, it will have a file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` named after it, containing the source entry. For example, for the `pi-rho/dev` PPA on 14.04:

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pi-rho-dev-trusty.list
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/pi-rho/dev/ubuntu trusty main
```

Simply locate the corresponding file for your PPA, and edit it to replace `wily` with `trusty` or whichever version you want.

Whether this will work without causing problems, there's no telling.

Comment: Thanks! As for your final comment, yeah, that's my other concern. Would downgrading to something like Trusty be long and painful?

Comment: There's no downgrading to 14.04 from 15.10. You'll have to reinstall.

Comment: Is that the same for any version? If so, how long does it normally take (obviously depends on loads of things but ballpark) for third party devs to update their sources after a new version comes out?

Comment: If it's a team managing their Ubuntu packaging, it happens quickly. If it's just some normal user running a PPA for their own convenience, perhaps never. You could contact the PPA maintainer for an update, or you could create your own PPA based on an existing one.

Comment: Doesn't sound too promising... I'll try and contact them but yeah, I don't know if they'll respond.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a given PPA download files for an older release by modifying its list file under /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ to use the release name you want to download from (eg: replace instances of the word "wily" with "trusty" to make your system use the Ubuntu 14.04 packages on your 15.10 system) but this is not a guarantee that the installed app from that repository from that release will work on the release of Ubuntu you are using, either properly or at all. You may just end up with a series of broken dependencies.